# Run Selenium grid 2 with custom firefox profile

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-grid

How to run Selenium grid 2 with custom firefox profile from code.

Here is code I'm having now:

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();

            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.HasNativeEvents, false);
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
            capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;               
            Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
            RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
            return driver;
```

The only thing I left is to force Selenium grid use my custom profile.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

```
 var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
// configure firefoxProfile ...
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();

            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.HasNativeEvents, false);
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
            capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;                
            capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, firefoxProfile.ToBase64String());
            Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
            RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
            return driver;
```

Comment: I already had this solution except I didn't know I had to call ToBase64String on the profile. Where is this documented?